# How do i center the panel-body, with input-label align with left side of input box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap: how can i make the panel-body align in center, but with the input-label align with left side of input text box?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" align="center">
        <form role="form" id="password-form">

            <div class="form-group full-width">
                <label class="input-label" for="userId">Username <Id></Id>:</label>
                <div class="input-group min-width-400">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                           id="userId"
                           name="userId"
                           required="true"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="closeBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button id="resetBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="width:150px">Reset Password</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you´re  looking for `.panel-body {margin: 0 auto; width: xxx}` instead of your align attribute..

Comment: It still not working. If i put .panel-body {margin: 0 15}, I can see the effect of this change. But nothing happen to .panel-body {margin: 0 auto}.

Comment: can you add link to your website or jsfiddle, incl. CSS?

Comment: Thanks, i got it. should also add display table

Comment: It´s not necesssary. Problem could be in floating .panel-body. If not, there is no reason why margin: auto shouldn´t work with block element. But you didn´t send CSS...